# Confusion about objc_getClass

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-runtime

In my Xcode project,I added the same framework for ios7 and ios8.I have renamed them to xxx-ios7.framework and xxx-ios8.framework.
I want to use objc_getClass("someclass") to get the runtime class.But the two frameworks have the same class.
How shoud I know which class I will get?

Comment: It's not good to have two different classes with the same name in a single application.  You can sort of get away with it sometimes, but it will bite you in the a$$ when you're not suspecting it.

Answer (score 1):

Although this may not be a great answer, you may want to use the same mechanism that Microsoft used in their MFC classes, which is defining a version number.

In essence, you would have a method, or methods like:

```
- (NSString*)classVersionAsString;
- (NSInterger)classVersionAsNumber;
```

which would return meaningful version information for you.

As noted in the comment above, you should be careful with having multiple frameworks with the same class names, since, the loader will pick the first class that matches a linker requirement by the dependent module or dependent application. When the modules are loaded, the class you get might not be what you expected.